# Why isn't my collision detection working in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

For simplicity I have a game and I'm trying to get my car to hit a wall. I've tried searching and I've tried several things as you'll see below, I'm not sure why I can't get it to work.

Here is the code in my `create` function:

```
    create: function () {
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        this.carSprite = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'car');
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this.carSprite);
    this.timer = game.time.events.loop(300,
        this.addRoad, this);
    }
```

Then in my `update` function:

```
    update: function () {
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.carSprite, this.wallSprite, this.scoring, null, this);
}
```

I am creating the `wallSprite` like this:

```
 addOneRoadSection: function (x, y) {
this.scoreCalculator += 1;
        if (this.scoreCalculator == 10) {
            this.scoreCalculator = 0;

            this.wallSprite = game.add.sprite(x + 100, y, 'wall');
            game.physics.arcade.enable(this.wallSprite);
            this.wallAnimation = this.wallSprite .animations.add('wallAnimation');
            this.wallSprite.animations.play('wallAnimation', 30, true);
            this.wallSprite.body.velocity.y = 100;
            this.wallSprite.checkWorldBounds = true;
            this.wallSprite.outOfBoundsKill = true;
        }
}
```

I am calling `addOneRoadSection` like this:

```
    addRoad: function () {
        this.addOneRoadSection(this.xValue, 0);
}
```

`addRoad` is being called in `create` using `this.timer`.

So in summary what this is doing is that when the `scoreCalculator` is ten, it add's a wall. That works fine, the wall is animated fine, but the collision detection does not work at all.

I tried moving the code inside of the `if` statement to my `create` function and it works fine with collision detection (but other things break so I can't keep it there). What am I doing wrong? I have a suspicion that since I'm calling `this.wallSprite` on average around once every second that it is being over written by the new sprite that gets added as `this.wallSprite` but I'm not entirely sure how else I should do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out. What was happening was that my initial inclination of me of me creating a new sprite and that over writing the other one was right.

Here is how I solved the issue:

in `create`:

```
create: function(){ 
 //Create a wallSprite array
 var wallSprite = [];
}
```

Now that I have an array when I add a new `wallSprite` in `addOneRoadSection` I can add the physics to each sprite like this:

```
   addOneRoadSection: function (x, y) {

            this.wallSprite.push(game.add.sprite(x + 100, y, 'wall'));
            game.physics.arcade.enable(this.wallSprite[this.wallSprite.length -1]);
            this.wallAnimation = this.wallSprite[this.wallSprite.length - 1].animations.add('wallAnimation');
            this.wallSprite[this.wallSprite.length - 1].animations.play('wallAnimation', 30, true);
            this.wallSprite[this.wallSprite.length -1].body.velocity.y = 100;
            this.wallSprite[this.wallSprite.length - 1].checkWorldBounds = true;
            this.wallSprite[this.wallSprite.length -1].outOfBoundsKill = true;
}
```

Finally in `update` I just need to do this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < this.wallSprite.length; i++) {
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.car, this.wallSprite, this.scoring, null, this);
    }
```

Voila - collision detection works for every sprite now.